# tabs icons highlight on swipe

Tags: android, tabs, swipe, highlight

I've customized my tabs in an Android app to have icons instead of text. However, the text labels were highlighted when selected. I've solved this by the OnTabSelectedListener, where a brighter icon is set. But I still don't know how to achiieve that native effect of highlighting when over of half of swipe from one page to another.

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an `OnTabSelectedListener`, you should use icons that *change themselves* based on whether or not they are selected.

If your icons are vector drawables, then you can use a **Color state list** to change their colors automatically. Here's what that might look like for a pencil icon:

- res/color/blue_when_selected.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#0000ff"/>
    <item android:color="#aaaaaa"/>
</selector>
```

- res/drawable/ic_pencil.xml

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/blue_when_selected"
        android:pathData="M3,17.25V21h3.75L17.81,9.94l-3.75,-3.75L3,17.25z
        M20.71,7.04c0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.02 0,-1.41l-2.34,-2.34c-0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0l-1.83,1.83 3.75,3.75 1.83,-1.83z"/>

</vector>
```

Now, wherever you set up your tab icons, if you use `R.drawable.ic_pencil`, you'll see that you get automatic color switching.

---

If your icons are .png files, then you can use a **State list drawable** to achieve the same effect. Imagine you have `res/drawable-mdpi/icon_normal.png` and `res/drawable-mdpi/icon_selected.png`. Then you could have this:

- res/drawable/icon.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon_selected"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon_normal"/>

</selector>
```

Again, if you use `R.drawable.icon`, you'll see that you get automatic switching between the two .png files.